# design/structuring a large/enterprice signalr core project - multiple hubs? only one hub?

Tags: signalr, asp.net-core-signalr, visual-studio-project

How to structure a SignalR core project for an enterprise application?
An application that has a lot of functionalities as so a lot of classes and methods to invoke.

- Multiple hubs for different areas?
- Only one hub that dispatch to different classes?
- How to arrange the project folders?
- I can't find any viable example over the simple tutorials?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can I ask what structure you ended up going with?  I’m in a similar situation. 

One thing I’ve found so far is hub contexts do not persist between hubs, so multiple hubs could be a no go if you are using hub contexts to maintain client  identity or state.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that this question will be closed because it is not to a specific problem but I will put my suggestion.

Since you will do a lot with SignalR and it would need to resolve different specific problems I would recommend to create a `.NET Core Web Application` to connect your product with this service using SignalR. You should start first reading this [SignalR documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

So you will have one app that is responsible to handle those connections and your app must have various hubs for different business logic. Create interfaces and managers that can be shared between hubs and inject the `HubContext` in the managers to call methods to the clients.

Since you mentioned *enterprise application* I would extremely recommend you to look at [Azure SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-pt/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-overview) to manage and handle your connections.

Answer (score 1):

Are you planning on using ASP.NET 4.x framework or .NET Core?

ASP.NET Documentation states that it makes no difference between single and multiple hubs from a performance standpoint. [ASP.NET Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#multiple-hubs)

That does not mean you may not have performance issues overall, that will highly depend on your design/implementation.

.NET Core does not appear to state either way. [Core Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-3.1#create-and-use-hubs)

According to their GitHub repo, you can have multiple if you want. Understanding that one of the differences is that under .NET Core each hub will have its own client connection.